# Adding one day in T-Sql give error Incorrect syntax near '1'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

```
SELECT *  from [TableName]
WHERE
convert(varchar, News.PublishDate , 14)
 BETWEEN convert(varchar, @SearchStringDate, 14) 
 AND  (DATE_ADD((convert(varchar, @SearchStringDate, 14)), INTERVAL  1 DAY))
```

Incorrect syntax near '1'.

what is not correct? how to solve the problem? please help me

Comment: is this for SQL-Server or some other DBMS? I think that it has `DATEADD()`, not `DATE_ADD()`

Comment: What is the datatype of `PublishDate` anyway? This is unsargable even if you fix the syntax errors.

Comment: @MartinSmith PublishDate is date

Comment: And what is the intention of the query?

Comment: [Please stop declaring varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: I don't think SQL Server supports ANSI style interval literals. And if it did, the correct syntax would be: `INTERVAL '1' DAY`

Comment: @a_horse not yet, [but possibly soon](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/432281/sql-server-doesnt-have-an-ansi-interval-data-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query would compile:

```
select *
from News
where
    convert(varchar, News.PublishDate , 14)
    between convert(varchar, @SearchStringDate, 14) 
    and dateadd(day, 1, convert(varchar, @SearchStringDate, 14))
```

But I don't get what results do you want to get. According to [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), 14 is `'hh:mi:ss:mmm'` format. If you want to get records for one date, try this (don't know what format your `@SearchStringDate` is, it's better to use `convert` with appropriate format):

```
select *
from News
where
    News.PublishDate >= cast(@SearchStringDate as date) and
    News.PublishDate < dateadd(day, 1, cast(@SearchStringDate as date))
```

Notice also that here I'm using `PublishDate` instead of `convert...` - so indexes on this columng could be used.

Comment: Is it necessary to convert everything to varchar?  That can get expensive.

Comment: @DanPichelman actually it's strange because 14 format is hh:mm:ss

Comment: +1 For second query. I presume that they probably need something like that.

Comment: @MartinSmith I just worry about format of @SearchStringDate - if it's something like `1/1/2013` it could give incorrect results..

Comment: Much better solution.  Stay away from modifying your search columns with a function.  If you do that, the query analyzer will not be able to use any indexes.  Good solution Roman!

Comment: @user2577687 thanks, just decided to write about it as a notice :) sometimes my not so good english stops me from writing more detailed answer, but SO helps me in this to :)